# How to use Mozilla Location Service as network location provider?

Tags: location-services

[Mozilla Location Service](https://location.services.mozilla.com/) (MLS) can derive a location from cell towers and wi-fi networks in the vicinity, just like Google's network location service.

But how can I configure my Android system so that it provides MLS to apps just like the Google network location service is provided now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MLS wiki has a [list of community-provided software using MLS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CloudServices/Location/Software#Android). There, you find a link to [Ichnaea NLP Backend](https://github.com/microg/IchnaeaNlpBackend).

And that is exactly the piece of software you are looking for. Because it is an implementation of [Unified NLP](https://github.com/microg/UnifiedNlp), the de-facto standard of non-Google network location provider services employed in Custom ROMs. See the [Unified NPL README](https://github.com/microg/UnifiedNlp#installation) for installation of Unified NLP and a backend, in your case Ichnaea NLP.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is also available on F-Droid as MozillaNLPBackend.